# How to get the line of text in between two words in the text file?

Tags: sed

I want to find the text which are coming in between two words, and this two words are not on same line, both are present on different lines, so I want to find the lines (text of lines) which are coming in between words

For example:

```
This is an example
first

second
third
vs.

fourth
```

so I want to find the text between `first` and 'vs.' words.
How do I get this with sed command?

Answer (score 1):

You can use range patterns:

```
~$ sed -n '/first/,/vs/p' f
first

second
third
vs.
```

Everything between `first` and `vs` is printed (`p`), everything else is not `-n`.

If you don't want the patterns:

```
~$ sed -n '
    /first/,/vs./ {
      /first/n
      /vs/ !p
    }
' f

second
third
```

`/first/n` skip over the line that has first, and for everything that doesn't match `vs`, print (`!p`)
Or

```
~$ sed -n '
    /first/,/vs./ {
      /first/n
      /vs/n
      p
    }
' f

second
third
```

skip if matches `first` or `vs`, print otherwise.

---

To end after the first "selection", you just have to quit (`q`) after matching `vs`:

```
~$ sed -n '/first/,/vs/p;/vs/q' f f
```

or

```
~$ sed -n '
    /first/,/vs./ {
      /first/n
      /vs/q
      p
    }
' f f
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/first/ { :loop; n; /vs/q; p; b loop }' filename
```

That is:

```
/first/ {    # when you encounter a line that matches /first/ (contains it)
  :loop      # in a loop:
  n          # fetch the next line
  /vs/q      # if it contains "vs", quit
  p          # otherwise print it
  b loop     # and loop.
}
```

The advantage is that the patterns need not be specified twice. To include the pattern range boundaries, use

```
sed -n '/first/ { p; :loop; n; p; /vs/q; b loop }' filename
```

By the way, had you not wanted only the first match, there would have been a nifty trick to get rid of the starting and finishing lines of a pattern range without repeating yourself, which is

```
sed -n '/first/,/vs/ { //!p }' filename
```

The trick is that `//` repeats the last attempted match. In this context, that is the last attempted pattern range border -- `/first/` the first time and `/vs/` thereafter. `//!p` means "if the last attempted match did not succeed, print." In this case, that translates to: "if this line is not a pattern range border, print it."

Comment: How can I use the case insensitive with above regex ?

Comment: Yes. Use `/first/I` and `/vs/I q` instead of `/first/` and `/vs/ q`, respectively.

Comment: If I want a text from first to vs next line and vs next line is \n, what are the changes are required in the above expression?

Comment: You mean an empty line? `/^$/` instead of `/vs/`. `^` is the start of the line, `$` the end, so `^$` matches if the start of the line is directly followed by its end.

Comment: the empty line is present after the `vs.`, actually I needed such pattern for fetching the particular text and after the empty some text is present